# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (19954,2) into shape (19954)

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science, seaborn, valueerror

I am trying to plot a  seaborn pairplot of only certain columns from a dataframe of shape(19954, 53),with a code attached and am getting an above mentioned error. Any thoughts?[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMhpC.png)

Comment: For being able to reproduce please provide code as text, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

The term broadcast indicates the fact that you have **separate array sizes which need to be matched**.

To solve this, follow the steps:

1. Check which array it's talking about (19954 x 2).
2. See which array demands the shape of 19954
3. Accordingly make the changes where broadcasting is possible (Tutorial: https://deeplizard.com/learn/video/6_33ulFDuCg)